# Mass migration of Crystal Reports from v10 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, automation, migration

I have been tasked with reviewing "SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010" and the "SAP Crystal Reports 2011" standalone as potential upgrade paths from Crystal Reports v10.

I've installed the extension to Visual Studio 2010 (and went through the common troubles of updating the runtime to get the viewer working) and can open report files and save them. Consequently, I get the "this report was saved in a previous version of CR, saving will upgrade the report file format" dialog. I've tested on a couple of reports and the conversion goes ahead smoothly and the resultant file remains compatible with our server software.

My problem is I have over 1,500 reports. I'd like to avoid opening each one in turn and saving/converting individually. Is there a way to convert all the report files in one fell swoop? Some means of scripting Visual Studio to do it, maybe?

Notes:

1. I've added every report file to a project and attempted to Save All... no dice.
2. I must convert every single report now. It's not an option to just convert those that need changes when they need changes.
3. My work network access is locked down pretty tight. The bureaucratic process to get any utilities or tools installed on my machine is **INTENSE** and must be justified.
4. We don't use any features of CR standalone that aren't shipped with VS.

P.S. It's worth re-iterating that I'm also reviewing CR2011. I'll need to do the same thing with the standalone designer too.

Comment: The first question is... why? What do you gain by re-saving the report files in the newer versions?

Comment: Actually, the first question is "how". I should know. I asked it.

But, I admit I asked the same thing when I was given this seemingly pointless task. It's risk mitigation, primarily. A push by computer-illiterate "superiors" to ensure all our tools are properly supported.

Comment: For VS2010, you could easily create a simple program to open each .rpt file in a directory and then re-save it (The web is full of examples in the language of your choice). Doing this in CR2011 is a little trickier... I'd try a script in something like AutoIT.

Comment: I'm ashamed that this hadn't occurred to me. Years in dev management have robbed me of my most basic problem solving skills! Glad I gave it up when I did! 

Thanks for pointing out what really should have been obvious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Craig and Lan for their input (you get an upvote), but Ryan addressed my problem within the comments of my question (and even did so after I gave him sass!).

For those with broken scroll-wheels and/or extraordinarily short screens:

> For VS2010, you could easily create a simple program to open each .rpt
>   file in a directory and then re-save it (The web is full of examples
>   in the language of your choice). Doing this in CR2011 is a little
>   trickier... I'd try a script in something like AutoIT.

Thanks, Ryan, for reminding me that I'm working with an API. Not just a dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Windows PowerShell?  I've written a PowerShell wrapper around the Crystal Reports SDK named [PsCrystal](https://github.com/craibuc/PsCrystal).  My goal is to make it easier to script the mundane tasks that I encounter each day.

You should be able to adapt the (sole) example to suit your needs.  I will add more examples in the near future.  Feel free to help the project, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this tool will work for you:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CRDataSource.aspx

It is actually replacing the connection, but will upgrade the reports too.